# The compiler does not accept my JSON notation

Tags: javascript, json, string-parsing

"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token c in JSON at position 2" This is what my compiler says. In JSON I wrote:

```js
{ chGamma:7.5, chTheta:7.5, dgamma:0.01, distance:10.5, 
dtheta:0.03, freq:1, gamma:90, maaiveld:0.0, maxX:0, maxY:0, 
maxZ:0, minX:0, minY:0, minZ:0, panPointX:300, panPointY:300, 
persp:1, speedFac:2, straal:1, theta:0, zoom:1, zoomFac:2 }
```

When I feed this string in https://www.freeformatter.com/json-formatter.html#ad-output  it doesn't have a problem and translates it to the desired object. 
If I feed Chrome with this piece of code:

```js
function initViewValues(){
    var viewJSON = '{ chGamma:7.5, chTheta:7.5, dgamma:0.01, distance:10.5, dtheta:0.03, freq:1, gamma:90, maaiveld:0.0, maxX:0, maxY:0, maxZ:0, minX:0, minY:0, minZ:0, panPointX:300, panPointY:300, persp:1, speedFac:2, straal:1, theta:0, zoom:1, zoomFac:2} ' 

    var obj = JSON.parse(viewJSON);   
}
```

it comes back to me with the above mentioned error. What can I do?

Comment: JSON keys are writting with quotes `{"chGamma":7.5`. Just check the output and the hints under "The JSON format" of the website you provided. That is how it is supposed to be.

Comment: Please provide more details. Sharing error logs will not be so helpful to understand and provide a solution to you.

Answer (score 0):

#### This is how you can move from a normal Javascript object to JSON and back.

```js
const objectPreJSON = {
  chGamma: 7.5,
  chTheta: 7.5,
  dgamma: 0.01,
  distance: 10.5,
  dtheta: 0.03,
  freq: 1,
  gamma: 90,
  maaiveld: 0.0,
  maxX: 0,
  maxY: 0,
  maxZ: 0,
  minX: 0,
  minY: 0,
  minZ: 0,
  panPointX: 300,
  panPointY: 300,
  persp: 1,
  speedFac: 2,
  straal: 1,
  theta: 0,
  zoom: 1,
  zoomFac: 2
};

const objectJSON = JSON.stringify(objectPreJSON);
console.log(objectJSON);

const parsedObject = JSON.parse(objectJSON);
console.log(parsedObject);
```

#### objectPreJSON is a normal Javascript Object and not valid JSON. That's why you need to `stringify` it to turn it into valid JSON.

```
 '{ chGamma:7.5, chTheta:7.5, dgamma:0.01, distance:10.5, dtheta:0.03, freq:1, gamma:90, maaiveld:0.0, maxX:0, maxY:0, maxZ:0, minX:0, minY:0, minZ:0, panPointX:300, panPointY:300, persp:1, speedFac:2, straal:1, theta:0, zoom:1, zoomFac:2}'
```

This is not valid JSON either, the single quotes around the normal Javascript Object does not turn it into valid JSON.

The keys of your object need to be valid strings i.e. `"validString"`, `notValidString`.
e.g. `{ "chGamma":7.5, ...`

#### `objectJSON` is what your object needs to look like in order to be valid JSON.

Comment: While this is nice and works, it does not really explain why the initial code does not work.

Comment: Will add an explanation.